# JSJ-decomposition of a non-hyperbolic 3-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a $3$-manifold. Then you can split it over spheres. This is the "prime decomposition" and is unique. You can then split the components of this decomposition along tori. If you leave the components which are Seifert manifolds alone then this is called the "JSJ-decomposition" and again is unique.

My question is this:

> Can you ever split over tori if $M$ is not a hyperbolic manifold?

I am sure I read this somewhere, but I have been through, over and under all of the things I have been reading about them and cannot find anything which mentions this. So...help? A reference would be great, and so would a short proof. Both would be best of all!

(Oh, and if you know what tag this should be under that would be great! I am figuring general topology isn't quite right, but then neither is algebraic topology nor differential topology...)

Comment: Yes, of course.  Glue the complements of two figure-8 knots together along their common torus boundary.  That's a non-hyperbolic manifold with an incompressible torus, and if you remove the torus you get two figure-8 knot complements.

Comment: @RyanBudney Oh. Hmm...you wouldn't happen to know what I was thinking then? (That is, is there any "difference" between the hyperbolic and the non-hyperbolic case?)

Comment: Hyperbolic manifolds of finite volume have very few incompressible tori.  If the manifold is compact, there are none.  If the manifold is non-compact, the only incompressible tori are isotopic to "links" of the cusps.  i.e. the manifold has a subspace diffeomorphic to $[0,\infty) \times S^1 \times S^1$.  In the literature these are usually called *boundary parallel*.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thanks - I think I must simply been getting it upside-down (indeed, I think I only care about compact manifolds, but I'd have to check - manifolds are not my *thing*...). Also, why did you choose figure-8 knots rather than un-knots? Are the unknots compressible?

Comment: The complement of an unknot is diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times D^2$, so the $\{p\} \times D^2$ factors are compressing discs.